# Get a particular string from the main string in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

substring = "frTrig_worldcup"

main string = "0.10/BMM/fTrig_Mast/BOYU/frTrig_worldcup"

The substring value will change. "frTrig_xxxx" but "frTrig_" will be constant

I need to get the substring which is in the LAST PART of the main string. The issue is the "frTrig_" comes in mid of the string also

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using `String#split` here:

```
Dim input As String
Dim parts() As String
input = "0.10/BMM/BOYU/fTrig_MastrrRea0.01/frTrig_worldcup"
parts = input.Split("/")
MsgBox(parts(parts.Length-1))
```